# What is my router listening for on ports 5555 and 3333?

Tags: network, network-scanners, nmap, router

I recently discovered `nmap` and pointed it at my router out of curiosity. It found that ports 3333 and 5555 are open but doesn't recognise either service. I investigated and found:

- I can successfully make TCP connections on both ports.
- On port 3333, after I connect the router sends '0NTP00-00-00MAC00-00-00-00-00-00'. Nothing I send it in response seems to trigger it sending anything else.
- Port 5555 responds to HTTP `GET /` (plus any other HTTP query) with a simple 404 page [1]. If it's an HTTP server, why didn't `nmap` recognise it as such?

It doesn't look like the ports are accessible from outside the LAN.

I couldn't find any info about these ports on the web. Does anyone know anything about them? What techniques exist for investigating further?

[1]:`<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><H1>Not Found</H1>The requested URL was not found on this server.</BODY></HTML>`

Comment: What type of router and what firmware/software version?

Comment: Netgear WNR2200, V1.0.1.88

Comment: Welcome to Info Sec. This isn't an info sec question but a question for the vendor's support.

Comment: First Google hit: http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=72944

Comment: @schroeder that thread points to another which you can't access (or at least I can't).

Comment: Yep, there are one or two threads on Netgear support forums. None of them contain any answers. I guess I'll email Netgear but I highly doubt I'll get in touch with anyone who knows what TCP is :(